# How to get access to use Sora?

Tags: sora

[OpenAI Sora](https://openai.com/sora) was just publicly announced.

I would like to try it, but I cannot seem to find a way to access it.

How can one get access to use Sora?

Comment: Right now, only via a job at OpenAI or their contractors...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not possible yet, except if personally invited by OpenAI or part of the red team ([source](https://community.openai.com/t/looking-for-sora-beta-api-access-how-may-i-get-it/628253/31)).

In the meantime, one can create some videos via [Haiper](https://haiper.ai/) (gratis but limited to 2 seconds).